# How to create a valid signature message to POST an order to the Kucoin Future API?

Tags: json, api, sha256, kucoin

I am trying to place an order but it gives me this error:
{"code":"400005","msg":"Invalid KC-API-SIGN"}
I'll be so thankful if someone check my code and let me know the problem

```
import requests
import time
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import uuid
api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
api_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
api_passphrase = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
future_base_url = "https://api-futures.kucoin.com"
clientOid = uuid.uuid4().hex
params = {
"clientOid": str(clientOid),
"side": str(side),
"symbol": str(symbol),
"type": "limit",
"leverage": "5",
"stop": "down",
"stopPriceType": "TP",
"price": str(price),
"size": int(size),
"stopPrice": str(stopprice)
}
json_params = json.dumps(params)
print(json_params)
now = int(time.time() * 1000)
str_to_sign = str(now) + 'POST' + '/api/v1/orders' + json_params
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
passphrase = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())

headers = {
"KC-API-SIGN": signature,
"KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(now),
"KC-API-KEY": api_key,
"KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
"KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2",
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
response = requests.request('POST', future_base_url + '/api/v1/orders', params=params, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: could you solve this? I have a similar code and similar error

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
tickerK = "AVAXUSDTM"
clientOid = tickerK + '_' + str(now)
side = "buy"
typee = "market"
leverage = "2" 
stop = "up"
stopPriceType = "TP"
stopPrice = "12"
size = "3"

# Set the request body
data = {
    "clientOid":clientOid,
    "side":side,
    "symbol":tickerK,
    "type":typee,
    "leverage":leverage,
    "stop":stop,
    "stopPriceType":stopPriceType,
    "stopPrice":stopPrice,
    "size":size
}

data_json = json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))
data_json

url = 'https://api-futures.kucoin.com/api/v1/orders'
now = int(time() * 1000)
str_to_sign = str(now) + 'POST' + '/api/v1/orders' + data_json

signature = base64.b64encode(
    hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
passphrase = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())

headers = {
    "KC-API-SIGN": signature,
    "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(now),
    "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
    "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
    "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Send the POST request
response = requests.request('post', url, headers=headers, data=data_json)

# Print the response
print(response.json())
```

Please take care of the lines marked in red:

- Remove spaces from the json
- Add the json to the string to sign
- Add content type to the header
- Do the request this way

[image: response ok]